# A desktop application in Java SE to receive a file from a digital stethoscope via Bluetooth

Tags: java, bluetooth

I’m trying to make a desktop application in Java SE to receive a file from a digital stethoscope via Bluetooth.
The API Javax.comm doesn’t exist for Windows. I try the RXTX solution by I isn’t working.
Someone have a solution?
Thank you for your collaboration.
Best regards.
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/)? It conforms to the [JSR-82 Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr082/). IT also has a JSR-82 [Emulator](http://bluecove.org/bluecove-emu/).

Comment: Yes, i try. Using the Bluecove API, I discover the stethoscope address (device.getBluetoothAddress).
Now, I would like to transfer the file from the stethoscope to the desktop application. I think I have to use the OBEX protocol but I’m not sure. And I don’t know what instruction I have to use.
Can you help me?
Thank you.
Best regards.

Comment: It's been years since I played with bluetooth: You can see an example here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5329799